# Should I use Jython with Lucene or PyLucene?

Tags: lucene, jython, pylucene

I am working on a project where I need to do information retrieval with Lucene. I code in Python and not familiar with Java. The dataset will have 4000 documents.

After looking into this, it seems I can use Jython with Lucene or Pylucene. The project is due in 1 month. I have not set up Jython before.

Would you recommend I use Jython or Pylucene?
What is the learning curve for Jython with Lucene vs. PyLucene?
How challenging is it to set up Jython with Lucene vs. PyLucene?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Python then PyLucene should be easier since you will write idiomatic Python code (as opposed to calling a Java library from Jython).